# Creating a tdm with only one variable

Tags: r

So I need to prepare a term-document-matrix for each of the sets of text I want to subsequently run against each other in a classification procedure (rolling.classify() in Stylo package).

So I created a tdm of the whole text corpus, then want to make two sets only of selected texts, one which should contain one text only. So multiple texts works fine (a), but one texts only does not (b), I cannot do this?

```
freq.list <- make.frequency.list(words, head = 265) # Creating frequency list using only the frequencies of the 
# selected features from word-list (words)
word.frequencies <- make.table.of.frequencies(corpus = x, features = freq.list) 
# Document-term matrix of whole corpus and matching frequencies.

# Making two subsets now:
a <- word.frequencies[c(1,2,3,17,19,20,21,22,23), 1:263]
dim(a) # Double-check that it is the right no. of texts

b <- word.frequencies[18,1:263]
dim(b) # Double-check

> dim(a)
[1]   9 263
> dim(b)
NULL
```

data:

(used dput())

```
x <- structure(list(middleFr_Calmative_1946 = c("the", "calmative", 
                                           "i", "don’t", "know", "when", "i", "died", ".", "it", "always", 
                                           "seemed", "to", "me", "i", "died", "old", ",", "about", "ninety", 
                                           "years", "old", ",", "and", "what", "years", ",", "and", "that", 
                                           "my", "body", "bore", "it", "out", ",", "from", "head", "to", 
                                           "foot", ".", "but", "this", "evening", ",", "alone", "in", "my", 
                                           "icy", "bed", ",", "i", "have", "the", "feeling", "i’ll", "be", 
                                           "older", "than", "the", "day", ",", "the", "night", ",", "when", 
                                           "the", "sky", "with", "all", "its", "lights", "fell", "upon", 
                                           "me", ",", "the", "same", "i", "had", "so", "often", "gazed",
                                           "resolved", "to", "speak", "to", "him", ".", "so", "i", "marshalled", 
                                           "the", "words", "and", "opened", "my", "mouth", ",", "thinking", 
                                           "i", "would", "hear", "them", ".", "but", "all", "i", "heard", 
                                           "was", "a", "kind", "of", "rattle", ",", "unintelligible", "even",
                                           "have", "a", "penny", "in", "my", "pocket", ",", "nor", "anything", 
                                           "resembling", "it", "."), middleFr_End_1946 = c("the", "end", 
                                                                                           "they", "clothed", "me", "and", "gave", "me", "money", ".", "i",
                                                                                           "back", "mine", ".", "i", "added", ",", "give", "me", "back", 
                                                                                           "my", "greatcoat", ".", "they", "replied", "that", "they", "had", 
                                                                                           "burnt", "them", ",", "together", "with", "my", "other", "clothes", 
                                                                                           ".", "i", "understood", "then", "that", "the", "end", "was", 
                                                                                           "near", ",", "at", "least", "fairly", "near", ".", "later", "on", 
                                                                                           "i", "tried", "to", "exchange", "this", "hat", "for", "a", "cap", 
                                                                                           ",", "or", "a", "slouch", "which", "could", "be", "pulled", "down", 
                                                                                           "over", "my", "face", ",", "but", "without", "much", "success", 
                                                                                           ".", "and", "yet", "i", "could", "not", "go", "about", "bare", 
                                                                                           "-", "headed", ",", "with", "my", "skull", "in", "the", "state", 
                                                                                           "it", "was", ".", "at", "first", "this", "hat", "was", "too", 
                                                                                           "small", ",", "then", "it", "got", "used", "to", "me", ".", "they", 
                                                                                           "gave", "me", "a", "tie", ",", "after", "long", "discussion", 
                                                                                           ".", "it", "seemed", "a", "pretty", "tie", "to", "me", ",", "but", 
                                                                                           "i", "didn’t", "like", "it", ".", "when", "it", "came", "at", 
                                                                                           "last", "i", "was", "too", "tired", "to", "send", "it", "back", 
                                                                                           ".", "but", "in", "the", "end", "it", "came", "in", "useful", 
                                                                                           ".", "it", "was", "blue", ",", "with", "kinds", "of", "little", 
                                                                                           "stars", ".", "i", "didn’t", "feel", "well", ",", "but", "they", 
                                                                                           "told", "me", "i", "was", "well", "enough", "."), middleFr_Expelled_1946 = c("the", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "expelled", "there", "were", "not", "many", "steps", ".", "i", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "had", "counted", "them", "a", "thousand", "times", ",", "both", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "going", "up", "and", "coming", "down", ",", "but", "the", "figure", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "has", "gone", "from", "my", "mind", ".", "i", "have", "never", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "known", "whether", "you", "should", "say", "one", "with", "your",
                                                                                                                                                                        "every", "day", "several", "times", "a", "day", ",", "until", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "they", "sink", "forever", "in", "the", "mud", ".", "that’s", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "an", "order", ".")), class = "stylo.corpus", call = load.corpus.and.parse(files = "all", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   corpus.dir = "x", markup.type = "plain", corpus.lang = "English.all", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   splitting.rule = ("[ \t\n]+"), sampling = "no.sampling", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   features = "w", ngram.size = 1, preserve.case = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8"))


freq.list <- c("", "-", "—", ",", ";", ":", "!", "?", ".", "’", "\"", 
               "(", ")", "a", "about", "above", "across", "after", "again", 
               "against", "ah", "all", "almost", "along", "Already", "also", 
               "always", "am", "among", "an", "and", "another", "any", "anything", 
               "are", "as", "at", "away", "back", "be", "because", "been", "before", 
               "behind", "being", "best", "better", "between", "beyond", "both", 
               "but", "by", "came", "can", "can't", "can’t", "cannot", "come", 
               "comes", "could", "did", "didn’t", "different", "do", "does", 
               "doing", "don't", "don’t", "done", "down", "each", "either", 
               "else", "even", "ever", "every", "everything", "except", "far", 
               "few", "fifteen", "first", "five", "for", "forward", "four", 
               "from", "get", "go", "goes", "going", "got", "great", "had", 
               "half", "has", "have", "having", "he", "her", "here", "herself", 
               "him", "himself", "his", "how", "however", "hundred", "i", "i'll", 
               "i'm", "i’ll", "if", "in", "indeed", "instead", "into", "is", 
               "it", "it's", "it’s", "its", "itself", "just", "last", "late", 
               "least", "left", "less", "let", "like", "little", "long", "made", 
               "make", "many", "may", "me", "merely", "might", "mine", "more", 
               "most", "moved", "much", "must", "my", "myself", "near", "neither", 
               "never", "next", "no", "none", "nor", "not", "nothing", "now", 
               "of", "off", "often", "oh", "on", "once", "one", "only", "or", 
               "other", "others", "otherwise", "our", "out", "over", "own", 
               "perhaps", "place", "quite", "rather", "really", "right", "said", 
               "same", "say", "second", "shall", "she", "should", "since", "six", 
               "small", "so", "some", "someone", "something", "sometimes", "somewhere", 
               "soon", "still", "such", "ten", "than", "that", "that's", "that’s", 
               "the", "their", "them", "themselves", "then", "there", "therefore", 
               "these", "they", "thing", "things", "third", "this", "those", 
               "though", "three", "through", "thus", "till", "time", "times", 
               "to", "together", "too", "towards", "two", "under", "unless", 
               "until", "up", "upon", "us", "very", "was", "way", "we", "well", 
               "went", "were", "what", "whatever", "when", "where", "whether", 
               "which", "while", "who", "whom", "whose", "why", "will", "with", 
               "within", "without", "won't", "would", "yes", "yet", "you", "your", 
               "yourself")
```

Comment: Can you please provide the data you're trying to generate a tdm for? By the looks of your code it should be sufficient to just provide us with `x` and `freq.list`. See here for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes! Of course! I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```r
b <- word.frequencies[18,1:263, drop = F]
dim(b)
# [1]  1 263
```

Comment: Please feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it solved your problem